# The last time England beat a side on penalties in a major tournament was at Euro 96 against Spain in the quarter-finals

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

The last time England ***beat a side*** on penalties in a major tournament was ***at Euro 96*** against Spain in the quarter-finals.

From BBC.news

Does the phrase beat a side here leave out some words, otherwise a side can't make any sense here.

The preposition at in this sentence also confused me, why not use in here, for all I know, he refer Euro 96 to the European Cup in 1996 which is also a tournament.

https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/blogs-the-papers-44706168

Comment: **at** is commonly used to refer to tournaments, competitions, and the like. They can be referred to as things people *travel to* and  *attend* (**at**) or as things in which people *participate* (**in**)

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. Sorry for being unclear. What I mean is that the speaker can be speaking of the tournament  as something which teams and players attend, and therefore might use the preposition **at**; or the speaker could be speaking of the tournament from the perspective of a participant in its various phases, and in that case use the preposition **in**. It is a matter of (often subconscious) point-of-view.   *Are you **in** the tournament? No, our team didn't qualify.* OR *Why are you wearing an orthopedic boot? -- Oh, I injured my ankle badly **at** the tournament last week.*

Comment: Thanks @ Tᴚoɯɐuo. As you say, it's just a matter of point of view,  can I substitute the in for at in this sentence, like at a major tournament?

Answer (score 1):

No, but it is a slightly odd phrasing.

Perhaps the journalist was still excited after watching the match.

The verb "beat" needs a direct object, to name the person or thing that loses.
In a game (of football for example) there are two "sides". In football the two sides are the two teams, so your example is equivalent to saying

> The last time England [ie the England football team] beat a *team* on penalties...

Since the verb "won" doesn't take a direct object, it could also be phrased

> The last time England won on penalties...

Comment: Thank you so much. In addition, do you have any idea about the usage of preposition at in this sentence? Why not use in, as I think he implied the European Cup in 1996.@James K